# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1x^nf(x)\,dx$.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, definite-integrals, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on [0,1].

Evaluate  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx$$

My approach :

Consider $\int x^nf(x)dx = \frac{f(x)x^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}\int x^{n+1}f(x)dx$
by using integration by parts.

then applying limit with $n\to \infty$ we get  $\int x^nf(x)dx = 0$, regardless of the limits of integral.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: What approaches did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Why did my question get one downvote? I want to know this since I'm new here. Thanks.

Comment: This question's been asked at least 4 times in the last 2-3 weeks, the last time being YESTERDAY...and with exactly the same answer as the one here below.

Comment: Ok thanks. How can I quickly get whether my question exists here or not?

Comment: You are right. How should I mark my question as duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

$$\left|\int_0^1 x^nf(x)\right| \le \int_0^1 |f(x)|x^n \le M\int_0^1 x^n = M \frac 1{n+1}$$

Where $M$ is the maximum of $|f(x)|$ in $[0,1]$ which exists thanks to the [Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).

Now take the limit for $n \to \infty$ and use the squeeze theorem to conclude.

Comment: Why does such maximum M exist ?

Comment: @VikrantDesai Read the whole answer *carefully*

Comment: Got it now. Really thanks.